# sql injection in comment field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security, code-injection

I have a comment form that consists of 2 fields (title and comment). Database contains 3 columns id, title and comment. Comment is displayed based on it's `title` like domain.com/index.php?id=sometitle

The title field is properly secured for sql injection using mysql_real_escape_string, but comment field which is a textarea is left open without escaping. I can escape it, however i'm wondering what harm can it do to just leave it without using mysql_real_escape_string on that field knowing that title is already escaped and it's how the output is retrieved.

Comment: "i'm wondering what harm can it do to just leave it without using mysql_real_escape_string on that field" - how much do you value your data?

Comment: Isn't there parametrized queries in MySql?

Comment: @mitch. This is not the question. I'm asking so i know how this works.

Comment: He is asking can SQL injection work with `INSERT` statements, because all the examples he's seen use `SELECT` statements.  To which the answer is, yes, it works exactly the same.

Comment: @John I guess you're talking about prepared statements. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @Sinan - Yes, that's exactly what I'm talking about.  Why not use that to completely avoid the sql injection problem all together?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What would happen if someone typed this into your textarea.

```
some comment');DELETE FROM COMMENTS;--
```

If your query to insert the comment were something like

```
INSERT INTO Comments(Title,Comment) VALUES('$title','$comments');
```

then you would have a problem. the resulting query would be

```
 INSERT INTO Comments(Title,Comment) VALUES('some title','some comment');DELETE FROM COMMENTS;--'
```

or to lay it out in a more readable format

```
INSERT INTO Comments(Title,Comment) VALUES('some title','some comment');
DELETE FROM COMMENTS;--'
```

the --' at the end just creates a comment, to get rid of any extra SQL that would make it not parse properly.

Answer (score 2):

All unescaped strings can be used to inject SQL.

Comment: I can't make sense of this without an example to my question. How is the comment field interfering with injection.

Comment: Huh? I have no idea what your problem is.  There is no difference between the two fields.

Comment: If my comment is something like "What a great ');drop tables;--' website!" then you're going to be in real trouble.

Answer (score 2):

If someone uses SQL injection in the textarea, it will run when the data is submitted to your database, which is why you escape it first.

Comment: How does inserting the comment field cause sql injection. We are talking about input not output.

Comment: The link you provided talks about selecting and not inserting. It's opposite to what i'm asking.

Comment: @Pinkie Not really, since the `$_GET` variable of the `id` would be used in an SQL select statement.  Perhaps you should revise your original question... I mean statement.

Comment: @steve, thank you. I see what you mean. I found a good example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681583/sql-injection-on-insert

Answer (score 2):

Escape it.  Assuming users are the ones posting comments, you are vulnerable from injection in the comment section, which would be executed one they post the form, not request to view the comment.

Answer (score 2):

DO NOT leave that field un-escaped.  It doesn't matter what the field is being linked with.  By the time the query is formed the injector can be returning password fields etc.

To really clear out ANY attempt at using sql injection you need to be using stored procedures.  If you have access to it you should be using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).