# SQL injection on INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, code-injection

The SQL Injection on INSERT as described here doesn't seem to work with MySQL.
[SQL injection on INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681583/sql-injection-on-insert/6784869#6784869)

When I use this statement:

`INSERT INTO COMMENTS VALUES('122','$_GET[value1]');`

With this as the 'value1' variable value:

`'); DELETE FROM users; --`

This error gets returned:

`Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM users; --')' at line 1`

What's wrong???

PS: Someone suggested me to do an SQL injection with this as variable value:

`',(SELECT group_concat(table_name) FROM information_schema.tables INTO OUTFILE '/var/www/tables.txt'))-- -`

But it didn't work either, and returned a syntax error.

Comment: It would be helpful to actually see a printout of the actual SQL.  Not just what you think it is.  At the very least, the PHP code you're using, since what you've shown should work.

Comment: I tried this PHP code: 

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("sandbox", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO COMMENTS VALUES('122','$_GET[value1]');";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  
mysql_close($con);
?>

With this input:
sqlinjectiontest.php?value1=');%20DELETE%20FROM%20users;%20--

Comment: put it in your question, not in the comment

Comment: When using arrays in a string, you need to wrap the expression in {} `...'{$_GET[value1]}'...`

Answer (score 3):

Your injection turns a single SQL statement (`INSERT ...`) into multiple SQL statements (`INSERT ...; DELETE ...`).

However, the PHP mysql API [does not support multiple statements](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) in a single query.  (The underlying MySQL C API must be [explicitly instructed to support this functionality](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html), which your bindings do not do.)

Comment: So, you are actually writting that you can't do a SQL injection like this without opening the file, edit it and save it again. Something that isn't possible in a real world SQL injection.

Comment: I'm sorry, I quite don't understand that comment.  The MySQL C API as typically used, and the PHP bindings in particular, will not accept multiple statements in a single query.

Answer (score 2):

As @pilcrow points out, `mysql_query` will only accept a single statement.  Your example is actually two statements:

```
INSERT INTO COMMENTS VALUES('122','value');
```

and:

```
DELETE FROM users;
```

The PHP `mysql` API will reject this immediately, so you can't use that to test SQL injection.

Another problem with the statement is the use of comment characters.  The [MySQL Comment Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comments.html) states that:

> From a “-- ” sequence to the end of the line. In MySQL, the “-- ”
>   (double-dash) comment style requires the second dash to be followed by
>   at least one whitespace or control character (such as a space, tab,
>   newline, and so on). This syntax differs slightly from standard SQL
>   comment syntax, as discussed in Section 1.8.5.5, “'--' as the Start of
>   a Comment”.

So you have to have whitespace after the `--`.  If you use `#` instead, no following whitespace is required.

A simpler and safer way to begin your SQL injection testing is to try a simple SELECT:

```
$value = "1' OR 1; -- ";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = '$value'";

print "$sql\n";
// SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = '1' OR 1; #'

$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);

// Should return multiple rows (if your table has multiple rows):
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print "{$row['id']}\n";
}
```

As the PHP `mysql` API rejects multiple statements, some of the more commonly used examples of SQL injection won't work, and that's a good thing.  However, as you can see from the simple example above, it doesn't prevent other forms on SQL injection.

Think how a statement like this could be affected:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = '1'
```

Also bear in mind that deleting data is probably not of much use to anyone other than a malicious hacker who just wants to cause disruption.  Obtaining confidential data to which you are not supposed to have access, on the other hand, may be very useful.