# Getting values from database to label

Tags: c#, database

how can i get values from database to a label when i type an ID number and use a button? i'm just new in C#

here is what i got so far but its not working

```
String str = @"server=localhost;database=library;userid=root;password=1234;";
MySqlConnection con =  new MySqlConnection(str);


con = new MySqlConnection(str);
con.Open();
String cmdText = "SELECT * FROM `book` WHERE `Book ID` = '"+txtbnumber+"'";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, con);
MySqlDataReader myReader;



try
{
    con.Open();
    myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        String tittle = myReader.GetString("Tittle");
        String author = myReader.GetString("Author");


        lbltittle.Text = tittle;
        lblauthor.Text = author;
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: You're very open to Sql Injection.  It's strongly recommended to parameterize your queries

Comment: @Jonesy i don't get it since im just new at c#

Comment: @user3779333 take a look [at this quesion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681583/sql-injection-on-insert) for an example

Comment: @GrantWinney that is where i type the book number then when i press the button it will get the value/string of the Tittle and Author from the database into a Label

Comment: @user3779333 what we want to know if this is a reference to a TextBox control or directly a string that contains the value

Comment: @Jonesy i tried my code to a ComboBox that when i select a book number from the list it automatically fill the Label with the database values and it works. Now im trying it to make it work when i typed it in a TextBox and hit a Button

Comment: Is txtbnumber the actual TextBox? If so, use `txtbnumber.Text` to get the actual content of the Textbox

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
String cmdText = "SELECT * FROM `book` WHERE `Book ID` = '"+txtbnumber+"'";
```

by

```
string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM [book] WHERE [Book ID] = " + txtbnumber;
```

But this is still quite prone to sql injection. So you should prefer using parameterized queries:

```
string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM [book] WHERE [Book ID]=@BookNumber";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookNumber", Convert.ToInt32(txtbnumber.Text));
```

Comment: "its not working" isn't very clear :-) What's the concrete error you're getting?

Comment: Have you already debugged your code? Put a breakpoint at the top and see what happens. I could imagine, that your query simply yields no results.

Comment: @Grant thanks again :D Well, I'd still prefer square brackets, but that may be opinion based :-) I assumed `txtbnumber` being a string already, but probably you're right again and it's just a `TextBox`.

Comment: @khlr i tried ti put a breakpoint but the red circle turned into white and i have no idea why.I never used a breakpoint before but i did a research how it works i tried it on my other codes and it works the way it has to be but not in my current problem, it just turned into white cirlce

Comment: @GrantWinney i tried your code. No sign of error but the button is still not doing its job