# SQL Server : UPDATE, SET with apostrophe in data

Tags: sql, sql-server

The update statement below is throwing an error because of the ' within the ''

```
UPDATE Table 
SET [Company Name] = 'O'Donald Media Inc' 
WHERE [Company Name] = 'O'Donald Media  Inc'
```

Does anyone have a way to handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

When writing SQL *by hand*, use `'O''Donald Media Inc'` for the string syntax. The '' sequence in a SQL string literal is a special encoding for a single apostrophe.

However, *if done programmatically (ie. from code), use placeholders*.

- [How do I escape a single quote in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sql-server)
- [SQL injection on INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681583/sql-injection-on-insert)