# Tibco BW SQL Direct Activity. Is it possible to run multiple statements?

Tags: jdbc, tibco, tibco-business-works

I use Tibco Business Works 5.14.

I am trying to run multiple SQL statements in one "SQL Direct" activity. 
Tried with Oracle (ojdbc7_12.1.0.2.jar) and MySQL(mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar) jdbc drivers with no luck.

Example statements:

[image]

I see similar question in tibco community forum but no clear answer https://community-dev.tibco.com/questions/multiple-statements-sql-direct-activity

Is it possible to run multiple SQL statements using  "SQL Direct Activity" in tibco BW5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer:
Running multiple statements in "SQL Direct" activity problem is not related to Tibco "Direct SQL" Activity itself. it's more related to jdbc driver implementation and database settings.

Please see [Multiple queries executed in java in single statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement/10804730#10804730)

for running multiple statements for example in MySQL you need to add

```
?allowMultiQueries=true
```

to connection string

```
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql:///test?allowMultiQueries=true";
```

Please note that setting **?allowMultiQueries=true** also making your query vulnerable to various "SQL Injection" issues. Please see example [SQL injection on INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681583/sql-injection-on-insert)